# Dart's http package doesn't return anything in Flutter project anymore

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

I have this simple function :

```
Future<Widget> getDog() async{
    var res = await http.get(Uri(scheme: "https", host:"random.dog", path:"/woof.json" ));
    print(res.statusCode);
    if(res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception();
    
    return Image.network(jsonDecode(res.body)["url"]);
  }
```

The `http.get` function isn't working anymore. **It was fine before**, but it's now not returning anything, and the thread is stuck (the print function never gets called). **This problem also happens in one of my older project**. What could possibly be the cause?

The function is definitely called, as I debugged it and the breakpoint was activated. I tried adding the Internet permission on the android manifest, to no avail. `flutter doctor -v` doesn't give me any error. `flutter packages get` was also used.
I tried looking at older SO posts, but can't anything like my problem, at least not any with a working fix.

EDIT: Apparently this doesn't work when I'm opening the project at home. But it works when I'm at school for some reason, so I expect a network problem possibly?

Comment: *the print function never gets called* > try to check the place you've called `getDog()`.

Comment: What of it? The function is called correctly using await. The function itself is called, and I can see through debug that http.get is called, but it doesn't do anything afterwards (in this thread)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you see any exception in console ?

You can also try this:

```
Future<Widget> getDog() async{
    try {
        var res = await http.get(Uri(scheme: "https", host:"random.dog", path:"/woof.json" ));
        print(res.statusCode);
        if(res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception();
    
        return Image.network(jsonDecode(res.body)["url"]);
    } catch(error, stacktrace) {
        print("${error.toString()}\n${stacktrace.toString()}");
    }
  }
```

Like this if an exception is throw you can print it in console.

Comment: Nope, no exceptions. Otherwise I would have put it in my ask.